# invalid_grant User session not found on first IDP login of session

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, idp

When using the latest bitnami/keycloak image with a native application (public client), I keep receiving a weird error when exchanging my authorization_code for a token: `400: invalid_grant, User session not found`, but only on the first attempt before any sessions exist for the user.

First, I make a call to the auth endpoint with:

- `response_type=code`
- `code_challenge_method=S256`
- `scope=openid%20email`
- `prompt=consent`
- `redirect_uri=scheme://login`
- `kc_idp_hint=google`
- `code_challenge=<code challenge generated from RFC-compliant code verifier>`
- `state=<guid>`

Then, I try to exchange the received `code` for a token by calling the token endpoint (`POST`) with:

- `grant_type=authorization_code`
- `client_id=<my client id>`
- `code_verifier=<RFC-compliant code verifier used to generate the code_challenge>`
- `code=<code>`
- `redirect_uri=scheme://login`

Oddly, if the user doesn't already have an active session, the token call returns a 400:

```json
{
  "error":"invalid_grant",
  "error_description":"User session not found"
}
```

If I look in Keycloak after the auth call completes, but before the token call, I can see that the session does in fact exist. In fact, if I start the whole process over now that the session exists, I suddenly get a 200, along with my tokens.

What am I missing?